# Cannot use DialogResult

Tags: c#, wpf, dialogresult

I tried to use `DialogResult` to check an `Messagebox`'s *YesNoCancel*. I'm using the following code which I don't see any problem with:

```
DialogResult dlgResult = MessageBox.Show(
   "Save changes before closing?", 
   "Warning", 
   MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, 
   MessageBoxImage.Question);
```

But *Visual Studio* throws me error saying

> 'System.Windows.Window.DialogResult'
>   is a 'property' but is used like a
>   'type'

Comment: I think you're mixing up WPF and Winforms code. Check [this](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/05/28/wpf-dialogs-and-dialogresult/) link for more information. And I think you're looking for `MessageBoxResult` rather than `DialogResult`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a confliction here between the [DialogResult Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Y581) and the [Window.DialogResult Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult.aspx).

To solve this problem, you can use the fully qualified name of the enumuration. As the following:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dlgResult = ...
```

However, since you are using *WPF*, use [MessageBoxResult Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxresult%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to get the result of the message:

```
MessageBoxResult result = 
    MessageBox.Show("Would you like to see the simple version?", 
    "MessageBox Example", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare `dlgResult` as `var`. Then it should work

```
    var dlgResult = 
        MessageBox.Show("Save changes before closing?", 
            "Warning", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question);
```

Also `MessageBox.Show` under *WPF* does return [MessageBoxResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxresult.aspx) and not `DialogResult`. `DialogResult` is used in *WindowsForms*.

Comment: or rather, use `var` to hide a problem and avoid having to understand

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `DialogResult` is also a property of the form and the compiler thinks you are refering to this property.

You have several choices here:

- Use the fully qualified name of the type `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult`
- Use `var` to let the compiler figure out the type and get rid of the name collision

Answer (score 1):

`DialogResult` is not a type, its a property, you want the type `MessageBoxResult`

I can see from the question you are not using winforms. So the code would read,

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(
    "Save changes before closing?",
    "Warning",     
    MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel,
    MessageBoxImage.Question);
```

Answer (score 1):

just try with MessageBoxResult

MessageBox will return MessageBoxResult enum values

```
            MessageBoxResult dlgResult = MessageBox.Show("Save changes before closing?","Warning", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question);
        Console.WriteLine(dlgResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(
"Save changes before closing?",
"Warning",     
MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel,
MessageBoxImage.Question);
```

then use result to check