# DialogResult.OK on SaveFileDialog not work

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, savefiledialog, dialogresult

I try, when I press save in `SaveFileDialog` I do something. I trying fix but always something wrong.

```
SaveFileDialog dlg2 = new SaveFileDialog();
dlg2.Filter = "xml | *.xml";
dlg2.DefaultExt = "xml";
dlg2.ShowDialog();
if (dlg2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{....}
```

But I have error on OK - which say:

Error:
*'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'OK' and no extension method 'OK' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

I try fix with this code:

```
DialogResult result = dlg2.ShowDialog(); //here is error again
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {....}
```

Now error is on DialogResult say:
*'System.Windows.Window.DialogResult' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'*

Comment: If it WPF or Winforms?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264954/cannot-use-dialogresult . Same issue

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume that you are referring to `WPF` not `Windows Form`
Here is example of using `SaveFileDialog`

```
//configure save file dialog box
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "Document"; //default file name
dlg.DefaultExt = ".xml"; //default file extension
dlg.Filter = "XML documents (.xml)|*.xml"; //filter files by extension

// Show save file dialog box
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

// Process save file dialog box results
if (result == true)
{
   // Save document
   string filename = dlg.FileName;
}
```

**Other Example**:

In `WPF` you have to handle conflict between `DialogResult` Enumeration and `Window.DialogResult` Property

Try using fully qualified name to refer the enumeration:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dlg2.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {....}
```

Answer (score 2):

`DialogResult` return `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult`.So u can use like that=>

```
DialogResult result = dlg2.ShowDialog(); 
if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {....}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if dlg2.ShowDialog() is equal to DialogResult.OK just check if it is equal to true

```
if (dlg2.ShowDialog() == true)
{....}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old topic but I will give you the solution for it. The dialog result you're looking for (for savefiledialog) is .Yes or !Cancel so it looks something like this:

```
if (dlg2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes)
```

or

```
if (dlg2.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
```