# How to save a file by using serialize xml

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, file, save

Im trying to save a file from a DataGrid using a button for it but i dont know how to make it saving that and the user can choose where to save. Also having some problems on the code.

```
    private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var path = @"C:\\Users\\Tiago\\Documents\\Teste\\Save.xml";

            if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    xmlDocument.Load(stream);
                    xmlDocument.Save(path);
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }


    }
```

This is what i got for now.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: '}' invalid expression term

Comment: and serializableObject doesnt exist in the current context

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` at the end of your code :)

Comment: try this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656715.aspx

Comment: @NazmulHasan if i try that code it gives me a lot of erros..

Comment: which one link  or my ans code after then ?

Comment: where you get "fileName" should be  xmlDocument.Save(path)

Comment: like i dont know if im on the right lane. what do you mean?

Comment: now my only problem is the serializableObject

Comment: should be set serializableObject global or same method .. can you share serializableObject  where you declare

Comment: what do you mean "how can do it" ? if you unable to set  global scope serializableObject you can't access in  Button_Click_4 . share your code where are you declare serializableObject

Comment: Remove your `using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))` statement from your code. The `XmlDocument.Save()` will write this to disk, and the `fs` is locking your file.

Comment: i just have it like this private object serializableObject;

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'  now it show me this error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow user to choose the location and name of file, there is SaveFileDialog option available for you.

Here are the some of the links that can help you to accomplish this:

[MSDN Link_1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MSDN Link_2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Link_3](http://www.dotnetperls.com/savefiledialog)

Answer (score 0):

`using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)` missing a `)`

Comment: @Tiago if this is the error, please mark this is the answer. :)

Comment: the error is still there xD but u solve one of them @Cologler

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, you have a missing `}` curly brace at the end of your code. This might clean up a few issues.

**Secondly**, make sure your `serializableObject` is accessible by the `Button_Click_4` event. Set the `serializableObject` as a field or property to access it.

**To choose where to save** Use a `FileSaveDialog` to give the user the choice where to save.

Create one :

```
var fileSaveDialog = new FileSaveDialog();
```

and then show it:

```
fileSaveDialog.ShowDialog();
```

You can then use the filename that the `FileSaveDialog` object gives when "Save" is clicked.

This is a string - set your `path` variable to it.

Like this:

```
var path = fileSaveDialog.FileName;
```

See http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/dialogs/the-savefiledialog/ for a good tutorial on using the `FileSaveDialog`.

**Example:** (use this inside your `Button_Click_4` event handler)

```
var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog(); // Create it

System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog and set a result (bool) to whether the user clicks "Save" or exits out of the dialog

if (result == DialogResult.OK) // If the user clicked "Save"
{
    var path = saveFileDialog.FileName; // Set the path to save to

    // Use the path variable to save the file to disk using your own code
}
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**
Don't forget to use `using Microsoft.Win32;` at the top of your code.

**ANOTHER EDIT:**
I've updated the code to assign the `result` as a `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult` to compare `result == DialogResult.OK`.
See: [DialogResult.OK on SaveFileDialog not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539219/dialogresult-ok-on-savefiledialog-not-work)

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying/asking..?

Comment: when i save and close the program, the file where i saved it isnt there

Comment: This is because your `FileStream fs` object is locking the file. You don't need the `using (FileStream fs = new ...)` statement wrapped around the `try {} catch {}` block, as the `XmlDocument.Save` method is saving it to disk. It can't do this because your `fs` is currently using the file.

Comment: Step through your debugger (put a breakpoint at where you show your `saveFileDialog`). See what the `result` is, and see if the `savedialog.FileName` has the right value in and it is being assigned to your `path` BEFORE you save the file with the rest of your code :)

Comment: the result is null

Comment: That's why it's not saving, then. Make sure that "Save" is being clicked, also. Have a look here: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/dialogs/the-savefiledialog/ Other than that, I can't debug your code for you

Comment: Instead of `var result = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();`, try using `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();` instead. Then in your check, look for `if (result == DialogResult.OK) Let me know if this works: I'll update my answer if so

Comment: I know you're not, but your SaveFileDialog is a WinForms component. By initializing your `result` variable using the FQ namespace you can ensure that your result is not lost in translation; and you can compare `DialogResult.OK` (which is also WinForms/Win32) enumeration against it

Comment: OK - here's a reference that gives you an example in the same way I've mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539219/dialogresult-ok-on-savefiledialog-not-work

Comment: Do i need to creat a class for form?

Comment: I don't get what you mean? Are you getting a red squiggly error underneath `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult`? If so; you might need to include the reference to `System.Windows.Forms` in your project

Comment: Doesn't let you what? Can you be more specific, please

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) this error after i put the using System.Windows.Forms;

Comment: OK, this is falling outside the scope of your original question, now - start a message in chat if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

To choose where to save, you can use `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx). But this is a WinForm library, so you need to add `System.Windows.Forms` to your project references.

```
var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Can also use the `SaveFileDialog` class to choose a direct file path. This will just give a folder path. Make sure you're appending a filename to the end of the folder path's string.

Comment: Need to include a `using Microsoft.Win32;` at the top of your code

Comment: done but now haver a problem with serializableObject